# What's the idiomatic / common / adequate way of delaying a DOM manipulation until the browser is idle?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser

Say, I have several `<script>`s I want to insert in the document, but those `<script>`s are very low-priority, so, I'd want those insertions to execute when the browser is idle.

The [`window.requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) would seem like an adequate way to do that, but we shouldn't do updates to the DOM inside `window.requestIdleCallback`.

Passing the operation to *just* [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) doesn't seem adequate since it will be executed just on the next frame and **not** when the browser is idle.

Should I just wrap the `window.requestAnimationFrame` inside the `window.requestIdleCallback`, like this?:

```js
window.requestIdleCallback(() => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    /* Insert scripts */
  });
});
```

Is there a better / more adequate way?

The question isn't really scoped to the particular situation of inserting `<script>`s but to any situation when one wants to delay any DOM manipulations for when the browser is idle (which sounds like an extremely common usecase).

Comment: The official docs talk about this specific situation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API#updating_the_status_display

Comment: Well found. So a queue is a good alternative...

Comment: @icecub I read this article before asking. It seems like the proposed solution is a significantly more elaborated & less clear version of `window.requestAnimationFrame` call inside a `window.requestIdleCallback`. The problem I had with this example is that it's pretty long-winded, seems to be much more nuanced that it needs to be & shows a great example of a program that has no identifiable similarities with common day-to-day Web development usecases.